# python matrix linear differential equation

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I have matrix differential equation `diff(x) = A * x, x(0) = C`, where:

- `x` is `1 * N`
- `A` is `N * N`, and is a constant matrix.

I want to solve it with python. By the time I have found ways to get only approximate solutions, but I want to get an exact solution. What library can do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org) for symbolic mathematics in Python. In particular, look at sympy documentation on [ODEs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/odes.html).